# Alphabet Rangoli Challenge

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

The question is about printing alphabets in a rangoli pattern of size/dimension input by the user.

**Example:**

```
size 3

----c----
--c-b-c--
c-b-a-b-c
--c-b-c--
----c----
```

[The picture contains details about the challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nn84.png)

OR

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alphabet-rangoli/problem

**Sample Code:**

```
n = int(input('Enter a size: '))

alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for j in range(0, n-1):
    ls_1 = str(''.join(alpha[n-1:abs(n-(j+2)):-1]))
    ls_1 = ls_1 + ls_1[-2::-1]
    ls = str('-'.join(ls_1))
    print('-' * (((n - j) * 2) - 2) + ls + '-' * (((n - j) * 2) - 2))

ls_1 = str(''.join(alpha[n-1::-1]))
ls_1 = ls_1 + ls_1[-2::-1]
ls = str('-'.join(ls_1))
print(ls)

for j in range(n-2, -1, -1):
    ls_2 = str(''.join(alpha[n-1:abs(n-(j+2)):-1]))
    ls_2 = ls_2 + ls_2[-2::-1]
    ls_s = str('-'.join(ls_2))
    print('-' * (((n - j) * 2) - 2) + ls_s + '-' * (((n - j) * 2) - 2))
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Enter a size: 5
--------e--------
------e-d-e------
----e-d-c-d-e----
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
e-d-c-b-a-b-c-d-e
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
----e-d-c-d-e----
------e-d-e------
--------e--------
```

Is the above code that I have done...is it a good code to say?
Also, I couldn't find any other way to solve the problem.
(I am a beginner in Python)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Use built-ins

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

This is a very verbose and error-prone way of getting all of the ASCII lowercase letters.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alpha
```

will give approximately the same result.  It is a string, instead of a list, but Python strings are effectively just lists of characters.  In particular, `alpha[0]` will be `'a'` and `alpha[25]` will be `'z'`.

## Unnecessary `str()`

The result of a `''.join(...)` call will be a string.  Wrapping this in a `str(...)` call is pointless.

## Unnecessary `abs()`

`for j in range(0, n-1)` means that `j` will always be less than `n-1`.  In other words:

$$ j \le n - 2 $$

Consider, `abs(n-(j+2))`:
$$ j \le n - 2$$
$$ j + 2 \le n$$
$$ n - (j+2) \ge 0$$
In other words, the `abs(...)` is unnecessary, and just adds confusion.

## General Comments

Follow [PEP-8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (spaces around operators, etc).  Use functions.  Use a main-guard.

## Reworked & Simplified Code

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def print_rangoli(n: int) -> None:

    alpha = ascii_lowercase[:n]

    for row in range(- n + 1, n):
        row = abs(row)
        dashes = "-" * (2 * row)
        print(dashes + "-".join(alpha[:row:-1] + alpha[row:]) + dashes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter a size: "))
    print_rangoli(n)
```

## Format Specification Mini-Language

Python's format statement (and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)) use a [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).  This allow you substitute values into a larger string in fixed-width fields, with your choice of alignment and fill characters.  Here, you'd want centre alignment, with `'-'` for the fill character.

For example, `f"{'Hello':-^11}"` is a f-string, which places the string `'Hello'` into a field `11` characters wide, centre justified (`^`), with `'-'` used as a fill character.  Producing `'---Hello---'`.  Instead of a hard-coded width (`11` in the above example), we can use a computed `{width}` argument.

Using this, we can further "simplify" (for some definition of simplify) the `print_rangoli` function:

```
def print_rangoli(n: int) -> None:

    width = n * 4 - 3
    alpha = ascii_lowercase[:n]

    for row in range(- n + 1, n):
        row = abs(row)
        print(f"{'-'.join(alpha[:row:-1] + alpha[row:]):-^{width}}")
```

Comment: `def print_rangoli(n: int) -> None: ` 
Kindly explain this syntax. I couldn't get it. Why the `None` statement used here? @AJNeufeld

Comment: @GobindaDeb That is a [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/2912349).

Comment: Functionally, this is no different from `def print_rangoli(n):`, but with the benefit that Python Type Checkers can warn you if you accidentally write `x = print_rangoli(True)` that a) you are not passing an integer argument to the function, and b) nothing will be returned to assign to `x`. Syntactically there is nothing wrong with that statement; you pass 1 argument to a function expecting 1 argument. Functionally, there is nothing wrong with it either; it will print a rangoli of size 1 & assign `None` to `x`. But logically it is an error. The seatbeats are optional… and mostly decorative.

Comment: _strings are effectively just lists of characters_ — specifically, strings are sequences of characters.

Answer (score 4):

I think the general algorithm is OK, but you have a lot of repetition in your code! Also avoid writing out the alphabet by hand when you could have Python generate it for you. Here is the code without repetition:

```
n = int(input('Enter a size: '))

alpha = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(0, 26)]

for k in range(1 - n, n):
    j = n - abs(k)   
    center = '-'.join(alpha[n-1:n-j:-1] + alpha[n-j:n])
    padding = '-' * abs(k) * 2
    print(padding + center + padding)
```

I used a single for-loop that goes from `1-n` to `n`, so this covers both the upper and lower half, and I also made it so you don't have to treat the center line as a special case.